# I have carousel image slider but it's not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to show a dynamic image slider with the help of `carousel slider` but it's not working.

My code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid pt-70 pb-0">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <?php foreach ($gallery_imgs as $img):?> 
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); echo $img['thumbnail_url']; ?>" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:30%;">
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I do not know where I am wrong in my code.

[image]

Comment: r u getting any error?...what output ur getting?

Comment: "It's not working" isn't really helpful. What is it supposed to do? What is your expected input/output? Do you get any errors? Please explain a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your `path` in `foreach` statement.
Try to replace

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); echo $img['thumbnail_url']; ?>" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:30%;">
```

with next code

```
<img src="<?= base_url().$img['thumbnail_url']; ?>" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:30%;">
```

If it won't work, then make `print_r(base_url());` before `foreach` and look at the result. If you can get access to your image via concatanating this result with `image path` then you will get your image in carusel item.
In the same way check each `$img['thumbnail_url']` on validity (`$gallery_imgs` must be an array of image urls).

Comment: I upload image  in the question  that the output I get

Comment: @farhantechno, it would be much efficiently if you'll add concatenated urls instead of images.